# MKCoordinateRegion setRegion issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, mkmapview, mkcoordinateregion

I used this code for iPhone iOS 5.0 device. And everything was OK:

```
self.mapView = [[[MKMapView alloc]init] autorelease];
mapView.delegate = self;
mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 414);
[myView addSubview:mapView];
MKCoordinateRegion zoomRegion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(MKMapRectWorld);
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:zoomRegion];
[mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:NO];
```

Then I tried it on iPhone 6.0, and it crashes at the string `[mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:NO];`

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
 reason: 'Invalid Region <center:+0.00000000, +0.00000000 span:+176.06470039, +360.00004292>'
```

What should I change in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

In your case `[mapView regionThatFits:zoomRegion];` it create issues.. remove it :

```
MKCoordinateRegion zoomRegion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(MKMapRectWorld);
   // MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:zoomRegion];
    [self.mapView setRegion:zoomRegion animated:NO];
```

Comment: what I need is to show the whole world, what is theCoordinate ?

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to set `latitude span` and `longitude span` before `setRegion` like this,,,,

```
MKCoordinateRegion zoomRegion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(MKMapRectWorld);

MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion;
adjustedRegion.center = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
adjustedRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01;
adjustedRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01;
adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:zoomRegion];
[mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:NO];
```

Comment: what I need is to show the whole world, but your code doesn't do that

Comment: it, doesn't show the whole world, just the post inside the Ocean and with big zoom

Comment: Ok it shows with max.zoom so set `adjustedRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01;` and `adjustedRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01;`..